# JS/react Canvas painting app becomes slow after executing getImagedata on canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While painting I store the previous two mouse positions in a react state variable. This is done in order to be able to draw smooth curves using bezier curves. My problem is that if I use getImagedata function on the canvas then the app permanently becomes very laggy when painting. It seems like it takes much longer for the mouse position state variable to update.

I should add that the issue arises even when I retrieve only 1 pixel using getimagedata.

I tried to look a bit a devtools and noticed that while painting after using getimagedata, there are "paint" events that are very long (30 MS) but before there were no such events in the event log. Not sure why this is the case.

Here is the code:

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { useViewport } from 'react-viewport-hooks';

const res = 2000;

function Canvas() {
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#000000');
  const [brushSize, setBrushSize] = useState(5);
  const { vw, vh } = useViewport();
  const [prevPos, setPos] = useState({"x1":0, "y1":0, "x2":0, "y2":0})
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("painting");
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
  const [pan, setNewPan] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
  const [prevPanPos, setPanPos] = useState({x:0, y:0})
  const [isPanning, setIsPanning] = useState(false);
  const [zoomLevel, setZoomLevel] = useState(1);
  const [stateIndices, setIndices] = useState(0,0,0)

  function startDrawing(event) {
    if (mode === "painting") {
      const coordinates = getCoordinates(event);
      const WH = getWH();
      console.log(WH.w, vw, "aaa")
      const newPos = {"x1":coordinates.x, "y1":coordinates.y, "x2":coordinates.x, "y2":coordinates.y}
      const factor = res/((WH.w)*(zoomLevel))
      console.log("start: ", prevPos.x1*factor)
      setIsDrawing(true);
      draw(prevPos, coordinates, true);
      setPos(newPos);
    } else if(mode === "panning") {
      const coordinates = getWrapperCoordinates(event);
      console.log("pos", coordinates.x, coordinates.y);
      setPanPos({"x":coordinates.x, "y":coordinates.y});
      setIsPanning(true);
      // setPanPos(newPos);
    } else if(mode === "infilling") {
      const WH = getWH();
      const factor = res/((WH.w)*(zoomLevel))
      const coordinates = getCoordinates(event);
      const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
      let fillColor = hexToRgba(color);
      //let uint8bytes = Uint8Array.from(fillColor);
      //let dataview = new DataView(uint8bytes.buffer);
      //fillColor = dataview.getInt32(0, true)
      //bucketFill(ctx, Math.round(coordinates.x*factor), Math.round(coordinates.y*factor), color)
      floodFill(ctx, Math.round(coordinates.x*factor), Math.round(coordinates.y*factor), cssTo32BitColor(color));
    }
  }

  function continueDrawing(event) {
    if (isDrawing) {
      const coordinates = getCoordinates(event);
      const newPos = {"x1":coordinates.x, "y1":coordinates.y, "x2":prevPos.x1, "y2":prevPos.y1};
      setPos(newPos);
      
      console.log("aa", prevPos, newPos);
      //console.log("continue: ", prevPos)
      draw(prevPos, coordinates, false);
    } else if(mode === "panning" && isPanning) {
      const coordinates = getWrapperCoordinates(event);
      setPanPos({"x":coordinates.x, "y":coordinates.y});
      const factor = 1//res/(vw - 100)
      console.log("pan", pan.x, pan.y);
      const x_ = pan.x+coordinates.x-prevPanPos.x;
      const y_ = pan.y+coordinates.y-prevPanPos.y;
      console.log("panx_", x_);
      setPan({x:x_, y:y_}, zoomLevel);
      //ctx.restore();
    }
  }

  function setPan(coords, newZoomLevel) {
    const WH = getWH();
    const factor = res/((WH.w)*(newZoomLevel))
    const x = Math.max(Math.min(coords.x, 0), -res*(1-1/newZoomLevel)/factor);
    const y = Math.max(Math.min(coords.y, 0), -res*(1-1/newZoomLevel)/factor);
    console.log("asd", x,y)
    console.log("asdx", x*factor,y*factor)
    setNewPan({x:x,y:y});
  }

  function scroll(event) {
    // Your code for zooming
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    const wrappedCoords = getWrapperCoordinates(event);
    const picCoords = getCoordinates(event);
    const WH = getWH();
    const factor = res/((WH.w))
    const xw = wrappedCoords.x*factor;
    const yw = wrappedCoords.y*factor;
    let z = null;
    console.log("1z",zoomLevel)
    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      // User is scrolling down, zoom out
      //setRes(res*1.1);
      z = Math.max(zoomLevel*0.9,1);
    } else {
      // User is scrolling up, zoom in
      //setRes(res*0.9);
      z = Math.min(zoomLevel*1/0.9,res/4);
    }
    setZoomLevel(z);
    console.log("2z",z)
    const xp = picCoords.x*factor/zoomLevel;
    const yp = picCoords.y*factor/zoomLevel;
    console.log("xvals: ",xp, xw)
    console.log(-(xp - xw/z), "panxw/res:",xw/res, "res/z:",res/z, "xp:", xp)
    const postZoomX = -(xp - xw/z)*z/factor
    const postZoomY = -(yp - yw/z)*z/factor
    console.log("postZoomX: ",postZoomX*factor/z)
    console.log("postZoomY: ",postZoomY*factor/z)
    // const x_ = pan.x+coordinates.x-prevPanPos.x;
    // const y_ = pan.y+coordinates.y-prevPanPos.y;
    setPan({x:postZoomX, y:postZoomY}, z);
  }

  function stopDrawing() {
    setIsDrawing(false);
    setIsPanning(false);
  }

  function getWH() {
    const boundingRect = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {w: boundingRect.width, h: boundingRect.heigth}
  }

  function getWrapperCoordinates(event) {
    const boundingRect = wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: event.clientX - boundingRect.left,
      y: event.clientY - boundingRect.top
    };
  }

  function getCoordinates(event) {
    const boundingRect = canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: event.clientX - boundingRect.left,
      y: event.clientY - boundingRect.top
    };
  }

  function draw(prevCoordinates, coordinates, firstDraw) {
    const start = firstDraw
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
    const WH = getWH();
    const factor = (res)/((WH.w)*(zoomLevel))
    if (brushSize==1) {
      console.log("SINGLE!", coordinates.x, factor, (coordinates.x*factor))
      context.fillStyle = color;

      context.fillRect(Math.floor(coordinates.x*factor), Math.floor(coordinates.y*factor), 1, 1);
    } else {
      context.lineJoin = 'round';
      context.lineCap = 'round';
      context.lineWidth = brushSize*(1);
      context.strokeStyle = color;
      context.beginPath();
      if (!start) {
        console.log(prevCoordinates.x2*factor*0.5 +prevCoordinates.x1*factor*0.5,)
        //context.moveTo(prevCoordinates.x2*factor, prevCoordinates.y2*factor)
        context.moveTo(prevCoordinates.x2*factor*0.5 +prevCoordinates.x1*factor*0.5, prevCoordinates.y2*factor*0.5 + prevCoordinates.y1*factor*0.5)
        context.quadraticCurveTo(
          prevCoordinates.x1*factor, prevCoordinates.y1*factor,
          coordinates.x*factor*0.5 +prevCoordinates.x1*factor*0.5, coordinates.y*factor*0.5 + prevCoordinates.y1*factor*0.5)
      } else {
        context.moveTo(coordinates.x*factor, coordinates.y*factor)
        context.lineTo(coordinates.x*factor, coordinates.y*factor);
      }
      context.closePath();
      context.stroke();
    }

  }


  function cssTo32BitColor(cssColor) {
      const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
      ctx.canvas.width = 1;
      ctx.canvas.height = 1;
      
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
      ctx.fillStyle = cssColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
      const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
      return new Uint32Array(imgData.data.buffer)[0];    
    };

  
  
  function floodFill(ctx, x_, y_, fillColor) {
    const maxr = 1000
    const x = maxr/2
    const y = maxr/2
    // read the pixels in the canvas
    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(x_ - maxr/2, y_ - maxr/2, maxr,maxr)//ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    console.log(typeof fillColor)
    console.log(typeof 0xFFFFFF)
    console.log(x,y,fillColor)
    // make a Uint32Array view on the pixels so we can manipulate pixels
    // one 32bit value at a time instead of as 4 bytes per pixel
    const pixelData = {
      width: maxr,
      height: maxr,
      data: new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer),
    };
  
    // get the color we're filling
    const targetColor = getPixel(maxr, pixelData, x, y);
    
    // check we are actually filling a different color
    if (targetColor !== fillColor) {
      const spansToCheck = [];
      
      function addSpan(left, right, y, direction) {
        spansToCheck.push({left, right, y, direction});
      }
      
      function checkSpan(left, right, y, direction) {
        let inSpan = false;
        let start;
        let x;
        for (x = left; x < right; ++x) {
          const xcolor = getPixel(maxr, pixelData, x, y);
          if (xcolor === targetColor) {
            if (!inSpan) {
              inSpan = true;
              start = x;
            }
          } else {
            if (inSpan) {
              inSpan = false;
              addSpan(start, x - 1, y, direction);
            }
          }
        }
        if (inSpan) {
          inSpan = false;
          addSpan(start, x - 1, y, direction);
        }
      }
      function dp(array1, array2) {
        switch (array1.length) {
          case 3:
            return array1[0] * array2[0] + array1[1] * array2[1] + array1[2] * array2[2];
          case 4:
            return array1[0] * array2[0] + array1[1] * array2[1] + array1[2] * array2[2] + array1[3] * array2[3];
          default:
            throw new Error('Array length must be 3 or 4');
        }
      };
      function checkLinear(x, y, c, left, t1=0.15, t2=0) {
        const fc = toColor(fillColor);
        const ic1 = toColor(targetColor);
        const mc = toColor(c);
        const oc1 = toColor(getPixel(maxr, pixelData, x + (left?-1:1), y+1));
        const oc2 = toColor(getPixel(maxr, pixelData, x + (left?-1:1), y-1));
        console.log("ccc",oc1,oc2, fc,ic1,mc,maxr, maxr, x, x + (left?-1:1), y+1)
        
        const o1 = [oc1[0]-mc[0], oc1[1]-mc[1], oc1[2]-mc[2]];
        const o2 = [oc2[0]-mc[0], oc2[1]-mc[1], oc2[2]-mc[2]];
        const i_ = [ic1[0]-mc[0], ic1[1]-mc[1], ic1[2]-mc[2]];

        const dot1 = dp(i_, o1);
        const dot2 = dp(i_, o2);
        const a1 = dot1/(Math.sqrt(dp(i_,i_))*Math.sqrt(dp(o1,o1)));
        const a2 = dot2/(Math.sqrt(dp(i_,i_))*Math.sqrt(dp(o2,o2)));

        console.log("dots",dot1,dot2, a1,a2)
        if(a1 < a2 && dot1 < 0 && a1 < -1.90) {
          const io = [ic1[0]-oc1[0], ic1[1]-oc1[1], ic1[2]-oc1[2]];
          const dot = dp(io,i_)/dp(io, io);
          const newColor = toNum([fc[0]*dot + oc1[0]*(1-dot), fc[1]*dot + oc1[1]*(1-dot), fc[2]*dot + oc1[2]*(1-dot)])
          //console.log(dot,"dot", newColor, toColor(toNum(newColor)))
          if(newColor === targetColor || newColor === fillColor) {
            return [false, -1]
          } else {
            return [true, newColor]
          }
        } else if(dot2 < 0 && a2 < -1.90) {
          const io = [ic1[0]-oc2[0], ic1[1]-oc2[1], ic1[2]-oc2[2]];
          const dot = dp(io,i_)/dp(io, io)
          const newColor = toNum([fc[0]*(dot) + oc2[0]*(1-dot), fc[1]*(dot) + oc2[1]*(1-dot), fc[2]*(dot) + oc2[2]*(1-dot)])
          //console.log(dot,"dot", newColor, toColor(toNum(newColor)))
          if(newColor === targetColor || newColor === fillColor) {
            return [false, -1]
          } else {
            return [true, newColor]
          }
        }
        return [false, -1]
      }
      
      addSpan(x, x, y, 0);
      let c = 0;
      while (spansToCheck.length > 0) {
        const {left, right, y, direction} = spansToCheck.pop();
        
        // do left until we hit something, while we do this check above and below and add
        let l = left;
        let i = 0;
        for (;;) {
          --l;
          const xcolor = getPixel(maxr, pixelData, l, y);
          if (xcolor !== targetColor) {
            if (xcolor === -1) {
              break
            }
            const [linear, newColor] = checkLinear(l, y, xcolor, true);
            if(!linear) {
              break
            } else {
              ++i;
              pixelData.data[y * maxr + l ] = newColor;
            }
          }
        }
        ++l
        
        let r = right;
        let j = 0;
        for (;;) {
          ++r;
          const xcolor = getPixel(maxr, pixelData, r, y);
          if (xcolor !== targetColor) {
            if (xcolor === -1) {
              break
            }
            const [linear, newColor] = checkLinear(r, y, xcolor, true);
            if(!linear) {
              break
            } else {
              ++j;
              pixelData.data[y * maxr + r] = newColor;
            }
          }
        }
  
        const lineOffset = y * maxr;
        console.log("off", i,j,r-l, lineOffset + l + i, lineOffset + r - j)
        pixelData.data.fill(fillColor, lineOffset + l + i, lineOffset + r - j);
        
        if (direction <= 0) {
          checkSpan(l, r, y - 1, -1);
        } else {
          checkSpan(l, left, y - 1, -1);
          checkSpan(right, r, y - 1, -1);
        }
        
        if (direction >= 0) {
          checkSpan(l, r, y + 1, +1);
        } else {
          checkSpan(l, left, y + 1, +1);
          checkSpan(right, r, y + 1, +1);
        }     
      }
      // put the data 
      const w = ctx.width
      const h = ctx.height
      ctx.putImageData(imageData, x-maxr/2,y-maxr/2)//,0,0)//,ctx.width, ctx.height);
    }
  }
  
  
  function getPixel(maxr, pixelData, x, y) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= maxr || y >= maxr) {
      console.log("colorError")
      return -1;  // impossible color
    } else {
      return pixelData.data[y * maxr + x];
    }
  }
  
  function hexToRgba(hex) {
    hex = hex.substring(1); // remove the # symbol
    var r = parseInt(hex.substring(0, 2), 16);
    var g = parseInt(hex.substring(2, 4), 16);
    var b = parseInt(hex.substring(4, 6), 16);
    return [r, g, b, 255];
  }

  function toColor(num) {
    num >>>= 0;
    var r = num & 0xFF,
        g = (num & 0xFF00) >>> 8,
        b = (num & 0xFF0000) >>> 16,
        a = ( (num & 0xFF000000) >>> 24 );
    return [r,g,b]
  } 
  function toNum(rgb) {
      const num = (255 << 24) + (Math.floor(rgb[2]) << 16) + (Math.floor(rgb[1]) << 8) + Math.floor(rgb[0]);
    return num
  }

  function handleColorChange(event) {
    setColor(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleBrushSizeChange(event) {
    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
    imageData = null
    //const pixelData = {
    //  width: imageData.width,
    //  height: imageData.height,
    //  data: new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer),
    //};
    //pixelData.data[0] = 0xFFF0FFFF
    //ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    setBrushSize(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }

  function changeCursor() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 
    mode === "painting" ? "url('brush.svg'), auto" : 
    mode === "infilling" ? "url('bucket.svg'), auto" :
    mode === "eraser" ? "url('eraser.svg'), auto" :
     "default";
  }

  function newState() {
    
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "z") {
      state = "changed";
    }
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "y") {
      state = "changed";
    }
  });

  return (
    

    
    <div ref={containerRef} className="canvasContainer" style={{position: "relative", width: "calc(100% - 100px)", height: "calc(100% - 100px)"}}>
      <div ref={wrapperRef} className="smallcanvasWrapper" style={{position: "relative", left: 0, top: 0,  width: "100%", height: "100%"}}>
        <canvas
          className='smallcanvas'
          style={{
            position: "absolute", 
            left: (pan.x)+"px", 
            top: (pan.y)+"px", 
            width: (zoomLevel*100)+"%",
            height: (zoomLevel*100)+"%",
            background: "transparent", 
            opacity: 1.0
          }}
          ref={canvasRef}
          width={res}
          height={res}
          onWheel={scroll}
          onMouseDown={startDrawing}
          onMouseMove={continueDrawing}
          onMouseUp={stopDrawing}
          onMouseOut={stopDrawing}
          onMouseOver={changeCursor}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="pointerSelector">
        <div className="modeButtons">
          <button onClick={() => setMode("painting")}>Painting</button>
          <button onClick={() => setMode("panning")}>Panning</button>
          <button onClick={() => setMode("infilling")}>Fill</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="color-selector">Color:</label>
          <input
            type="color"
            id="color-selector"
            value={color}
            onChange={handleColorChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="brush-size-selector">Brush size:</label>
          <input
            type="range"
            id="brush-size-selector"
            min={1}
            max={10}
            value={brushSize}
            onChange={handleBrushSizeChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default Canvas
```

For debugging purposes I put the getimagedata function into the handleBrushSizeChange function.

Comment: doing a bit more digging with devtools I noticed that before using getimagedata, the page would only repaint the areas im currently paiting at, but after, every time I draw a stroke on the canvas, the entire canvas gets repainted

Comment: you can `useRef` for things like `zoom`, `pan`, `prevPan`, `isPanning`, `isDrawing`, `zoomLevel`, and probably many more. this will dramatically reduce the number of renders

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Would this in particular be useful for prevPos since it gets updated by every mouse movement?

Comment: correct. any time you use `setState` from a `useState` hook, you will trigger a render. See [useRef docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef) for more guidance.

Comment: a technique i use for heavy graphical application is `useRef` for as many mutable state as possible, and use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to update element attributes using the state. this gives fast, realtime feedback to user input without triggering heavy react renders.

Comment: another option is to consider something like [react-konva](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Intro.html) which tries to make canvas apps as declarative as possible. for data that is constantly changing, i found the re-renders to be too heavy and consume too much browser memory. i ended up using SVG, which already offers a declarative API (unlike canvas) and doesn't add a huge dependency to your project. ymmv